# getting strange chars through jquery AJAX function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The problem is that im getting strange chars at the beginning of the string.

Here is my code:

PHP Script:

```
public function get_hotel_phone(){
   $hotel = new HotelModel();
   $query = "SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE id_hotel=" . $_POST['id_hotel'];
   $hotel = $hotel->execute_query($query);  
   echo $hotel[0]['hotel_phone'];
   return 1;
}
```

Jquery Script:

```
function get_hotel_phone(hotel_id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:"id_hotel=" + hotel_id,
        dataType: "html",
        url: "index.php?controller=Booking&action=get_hotel_phone",                            
        success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
            $("#booking_phone_number").attr("value",response);
            return 1;
        }
    });
}
```

Screenshots:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/7nkz.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/163/gltn.png/

In the first pic I show the Alert box with the 4 squares.

In the second pic I show the Programmer's tool, and I don't know why I have the 4 red dots with \ufeff there.

I also have coded some Jquery Ajax scripts more and I didn't have anyproblem.

Kind Regards!

Comment: What is your PHP script outputting? Can you check the output independently from AJAX - and what do you get?

Comment: And what does $hotel[0]['hotel_phone']; return if you print it directly?

Comment: When I check it independently from AJAX I get outputed "767053", if I print directly I get "767053"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use JSON encoding instead of returning the response in HTML.

```
function get_hotel_phone(hotel_id){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:"id_hotel=" + hotel_id,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "index.php?controller=Booking&action=get_hotel_phone",                            
    success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
        $("#booking_phone_number").attr("value",response);
        return 1;
    }
});
```

}

and :

```
public function get_hotel_phone(){
    $hotel = new HotelModel();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE id_hotel=" . $_POST['id_hotel'];
    $hotel = $hotel->execute_query($query);  
    return json_encode($hotel[0]['hotel_phone']);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: didn't work, I though that I could return only a simple string from the php script to the AJAX script.

Comment: You have to echo the returned content in your "get_hotel_phone()" function.

Comment: So in your PHP it would be something like : "echo get_hotel_phone(); exit;"

Comment: Yes, I have it.The problem is that by some strange reason there are some character at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Ok, so maybe as someone has suggested, it must be a charset issue or page encoding issue with your editor, if you are under notepad++, make sure your page is encoded in "UTF-8 Without BOM".

Comment: I'm under notepad++ and im coding in "UTF without BOM"

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an encoding issues. Ensure you have the charset set

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="ISO-8859-1" />
```